# Install SQLSRV extension for PHP on WAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I've seen many of these posts and have looked through them all, but I still cannot get the SQLSRV extension running.  Can you help me out?  I will post all the information I have below:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- WampServer 2.2 32-bit
- PHP 5.4.3 32-bit
- Apache 2.2.22 (can't tell if VC6 or VC9)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client 64-bit

I downloaded SQLSRV30.exe.  I extracted the dll files to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext.

**In my php.ini:**

- extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/"
- extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

I know that SQLSRV30.exe is built as 32-bit.  This is why I have 32-bit versions of Wamp and PHP.  I also know that nothing in Wamp is non-thread-safe.
If I view phpinfo() I should see a 'sqlsrv' section, but I currently do not.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Refer : http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-admin/howto-installing-sqlsrv

Comment: Differences between your reference link and my situation:  I am using Apache instead of IIS.  I believe I am using a thread-safe version of PHP instead of non-thread-safe, but how can I tell for sure?  Anyways, there is no file called php_sqlsrv.dll from Microsoft's SQLSRV PHP extension download page.  There are lots of different versions of the sqlsrv file, all for various things like non-thread-safe vs thread-safe, PHP 5.3.x vs PHP 5.4.x, and VC6 vs VC9.  I found the download page here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: you can tell if it's ts (thread safe) by looking in the php folder.  TS installations use php5ts.dll where non-ts use php5.dll.

Answer (score 6):

If you are editing `c:\wamp\bin\php\php.ini`, do not edit that file just edit the one given by wamp server php.ini file, goto wamp server php, then php.ini then you get write ini file.

I had the same problem, this fixed it for me.

Also, make sure you right click WAMP shortcut and "Run as Administrator"

Comment: I didn't realize I had to run WAMP as Administrator -- must be an important step..

Answer (score 3):

I ran into some trouble this morning, but I found out I had a x64 WampServer... Which was not gonna work correctly.

So, I reinstalled a x86 WampServer, and followed everything i could find on PHP.net (http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php). Because I saw this post while i was looking for my x64 solution, I thought I would come back and try to help you:

1) If you have PHP 5.4.# on Wamp, i bet it's TS,VC9

2) Locate the correct 'php.ini' : mine is NOT in the 'bin/php#' folder, but in the 'bin/apache#' folder (C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini)

3) There are 2 SQLSRV driver versions, 2.0 and 3.0 , make sure you have 3.0!

From the looks of it, we have exactly the same Wamp version, so... I'm pretty sure you have to use the 'php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' and 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll'.

Answer (score 2):

Did you see your new dll in your php extensions list? If so, click on it and make sure there is a V by its name.
(left click on the hopefully green wamp symbol. php-->php extensions-->name of your dll)

I had a similar problem with php 5.5, SQLSRV31.exe, php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll and php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll. Miraculously it worked.

Comment: Also verify that the extension shows up in phpinfo(). Using WAMP, click the green W from the status bar, click localhost, and then phpinfo()